# Why do ideals arise naturally in ring theory in the same way that normal subgroups arise naturally in group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I guess my question is essentially that why being closed under multiplication by elements in $R$ for $I$ is required for $R/I$ to be a quotient ring.

Comment: To answer the title: just as normal subgroups arise as kernels of group homomorphisms, ideals arise as kernels of ring homomorphisms. As for the body: if $x = 0$ in $R/I$, then we certainly want $rx = 0$ in $R/I$ for any $r \in R$, and this is exactly what the property you mention implies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal subgroups $N\subseteq G$ of a group $G$ are important precisely because for $H$ a subgroup of $G$, $G/H$ has a group structure compatible with the one on $G$ if and only if $H$ is normal. More precisely, $aH\cdot bH=abH$ for any pair $a,b\in G$ if and only if $xH=Hx$ for all $x\in G$, if and only if $xHx^{-1}=H$ if and only if $H$ is normal.

The same idea explains the importance of ideals. In ring theory, the ring $A$ in question is an abelian group under addition and so any additive subgroup is normal. So, if we fix such a subgroup $B\subseteq A$ and we try to form a quotient space $A/B$, we notice that $A/B$ has a group structure compatible with the one on $A$. Multiplication becomes more complicated:
$$ (x+B)\cdot (y+B)=xy+xB+yB+B.$$
It turns out that the latter expression is equal to $xy+B$ if and only if $xB=B$ for all $x\in A$, i.e. $B$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $A$.